# Canon EDSDK Tutorial in C# "Canon Dll's not found" error

Tags: c#, sdk, edsdk, canon-sdk

I download the source only tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp). When I run it with connect my Canon 70D, I got the error "Canon Dll's not found" shown below. After clicking OK, the gui appeared but all buttons are grayout on the gui. There is a folder name is 'EDSDKLib' in project folder. I am quite new at using canon SDK and I don't understand why I am getting the error.

What is the reason of that? How can I solve it?

Error message:

[image]

Gui after clicking OK:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

author of the article here.
You need to put the DLLs from the Canon SDK into the output folder/beside the created exe file.

You can get those DLLs directly from Canon. They are free but you have to apply for it.

Depending where you are located, you need to go to one of those sites:

- [Europe, African and Middle East](http://www.didp.canon-europa.com/)
- [North, Central and South America](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/sdk_homepage)
- [Australia and New Zealand](https://www.canon.com.au/en-AU/Personal/Support-Help/Support-News/Canon-SDK)
- [India, Indonesia, Malaysia, Pakistan, the Philippines, Singapore and Thailand](http://www.canon-asia.com/section/developerresource/digitalimaging.jsp)

Comment: Hahaha awesome. How lucky I am :) I applied conon and got positive response.  I am using Canon 70D and which SDK should I download in this link http://www.didp.canon-europa.com/

Comment: congrats ;) I'd suggest to use the newest, should be a 3.x version number. The library is called EDSDK or EOS Digital SDK

Comment: Hi, I did it but I got an error. Check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421406/sdk-error-0x8d07-while-using-canon-sdk-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

Addition To Johannes Bildstein's answer, After you got the EDSDK files from canon, you need to add the files which are inside the DLL folder, into the 'Debug/bin' folder where your app runs

Answer (score 0):

2020 update: For some time now, it's enough to download the [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Canon.EDSDK/). This will download the dll(s) you need to the following folder:

```
C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\canon.edsdk\<version>\dll
```