# SDK Error: 0x8D07, while using Canon SDK in C#

Tags: c#, sdk, edsdk, canon-sdk

I download the source only tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp). When I run it with connect my Canon 70D, I got the error below.

What is the point I missed?

The Error:

[image]

The error occurs on this line:

[image]

And here is how the folder which includes EXE file looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem by letting the camera know there's enough disk space on the host.

Adding the line

```
CameraHandler.SetCapacity();
```

before

```
CameraHandler.TakePhoto();
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me also. But then other errors 0xA3 and 0x61 followed it, which was caused by not creating a folder on my PC for the image, as I'm running without a memory card. In your screenshot, the ImageSaveDirectory needs to exist. Then all went well.

Answer (score 0):

Error 0x8D07 stands for EDS_ERR_TAKE_PICTURE_CARD_NG

I'm not a 100% sure what it means but it's some sort of write error. To resolve this, format the card, switch off the camera and put out the battery for a few seconds.

This should fix the problem.